# How is the shutter speed set with the Sony Camera Remote API Beta?

Tags: android, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I have a Sony DSC-QX100 with the latest firmware (v3.00) installed. When I send the API call "setShutterSpeed" to the device with any parameter, the result I get is successful return value of 0 in the "result" object of the response JSONArray, which should mean that the call is successful. Yet when I check this with the API call "getShutterSpeed", it always returns the same value ("1/30") as if the shutter speed did not change. Also, when I send the API call "getAvailableShutterSpeed" it always returns an empty list. What could the problem be?

Comment: have you verified that your camera model actually supports changing the shutter speed?

Comment: Yes, it is listed in the documentation as a device that supports that with the latest firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the exposure mode was set to "aperture" which means that only the "F number" setting could be manually set. Changing the exposure mode to "shutter" allows the shutter speed to be manually set. Changing it to "intelligent auto" prevents shutter speed, F number, and ISO speed rate from being set manually.